# Laravel 5.4 Service Provider not loads after site opened

Tags: php, laravel

I have project in Laravel 5.4 I'm created new custom class and service provider for them. And bind this class to app in service provider `register` method. And write this provider in **app.php** config. But it's not loading when app is loaded. I write `Log` in `__construct` method of my custom class **Helper**, but log not writing in laravel.log file and other operations not executes in this `__construct` method. Below code from service provider.

```
public function register()
{
    App::bind('helper', function() {
        return new Helper;
    });
}
```

Comment: And in custom class not working Auth in __construct it may be for the middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be sure, you registered the provider in `config/app.php` like:

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Full\Path\To\ClassServiceProvider::class,
    ...
 ]
```

When you bind, it should be like:

```
public function register()
{
    App::bind('Full\Path\To\Class', function() {
        return new Helper;
    });
}
```

You can then alias `helper` to your classes full name:

```
App:alias('helper', 'Full\Path\To\Class');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind a class or create an alias, it will be automatically registered in the container. Just create a class, run `composer du` command and inject the class using its full class name including namespace:

```
app('\App\SomeNamespace\Helper');
```

Or using controller constructor, for example:

```
use App\SomeNamespace\Helper;
public function __construct(Helper $helper)
```

If you want to bind it to bind it to something like `helper`, you can do this:

```
app()->bind('helper', '\App\SomeNamespace\Helper');
```

And then use it:

```
app('helper');
```